Sidenotes with a long argument fail: how to add processing of long arguments?
I try to fix the problem with "long arguments" in \sidenote mentioned before (e.g. here, identified as a bug.)
It seems that the issue is with the code in the sidenotes package, specifically in the \sidenotetext when passed a "long" argument containing a blank line as third argument (i.e. the material that should go into the margin).
It seems that the processing of the "long argument" is not correct, but I cannot find advice on how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate, if somebody could point me to pertinent information, I try to learn LaTeX!
\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
{
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {
      \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}
  \refstepcounter{sidenote}
}
    {\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \@sidenotes@placemarginal { m +m }
{
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {\marginpar{#2}}
    {\marginnote{#2}[#1]}

A MWE  which places two sidenotes, one "short" (correctly) and the next "long" (with error).
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
    marginparsep=8.2mm,
    marginparwidth=60mm, %78.4mm,
    ignoremp=false,  %false = textwidth not including marginparwidth
}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% -- -- --- ----------  ----             ----        ---------------
\begin{document}
 
first SIDENOTE\sidenote{fist Line
    continuation.}  
and the remaining text

\vspace{3cm}
second SIDENOTE\sidenote{first Line
%\endgraf % blank line could be replaced by endgraph, works!

    second line.}  

\end{document}

It produces for the second sidenote twice the second line in the main text and nothing in the margin. The error messages are:

{@sidenotes@placemarginal {-NoValue-}{\textsuperscript {\thesidenote
\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF code was complete.
  \par  l.22    second line.}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My
plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Too many }'s. \sidenotetext code ...script {\thesidenote }{} #3}
\refstepcounter {sidenote}... l.22  second line.}
You've closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! Too many }'s. \sidenotetext code ...}\refstepcounter {sidenote}}
{@sidenotes@placemarginal... l.22  second line.}
You've closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
Runaway argument? {\textsuperscript {-NoValue-} first Line  !
Paragraph ended before @sidenotes@placemarginal code was complete.
  \par  l.22    second line.}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we recover? My
plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Too many }'s. \sidenotetext code ...}{\textsuperscript {#1} #3}}
l.22   second line.}
You've closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.


Please make your example self contained. Noone else have access to sidenotes2

@daleif: oops, this was my local (unaltered) copy. Bug is in the public version!

Problem obviously is that  \sidenotetext never checks #2 only #1 and it is getting -NoValue- from \sidenote. The author problably thought they were using O{} not o. Probably a good idea to inform the maintainer. Then again the package hasn't been updated siden 2016.

@daleif: Could you explain what you meant with  "using O{} not o"; my understanding of Latex is limited, I try to learn! The value of #2 is checked later in placemarginal - I have added the code above. Thank you for help!

The problem is with \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF that cannot be “long”.

The problem is twofold.

\sidenotetext accepts long arguments, but it calls \@sidenotes@placemarginal that doesn't;
even if we modify \@sidenotes@placemarginal to accept a long argument, it uses \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF which also doesn't accept arguments.

\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
    marginparsep=8.2mm,
    marginparwidth=60mm, %78.4mm,
    ignoremp=false,  %false = textwidth not including marginparwidth
}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{ m +m +m }
{
 \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {#2}
  {\tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \@sidenotes@placemarginal { +m +m }
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\marginpar{#2}}
    {\marginnote{#2}[#1]}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

first SIDENOTE\sidenote{fist Line
    continuation.}  
and the remaining text

\vspace{3cm}

second SIDENOTE\sidenote{first Line
%\endgraf % blank line could be replaced by endgraph, works!

    second line.}  

\end{document}



Great! Thank you very much. I will study your code tomorrow morning and hope I finally understand how to deal with long arguments (and produce my book).

@user855443 I just fixed two definitions in sidenotes.sty.

It works and I have edited my local copy of sidenotes.sty. (impoartant case: enumerations in sidenoets!) It was just adding 3 times a + --- so simple at the end, but to know where! I infer a general rule that a command with +m in an argument must call  commands with +m at the same argument --- as long as expl3 language style used (is the ExplSyntaxOn still required?). How to go from a +m to a command which does not take a long argument? - Thank you a lot for the help and the explanation, I learned a lot!
